# How to print green heart symbol in Python?

Tags: python

I want to print the green heart with this script: `print('\u1F49A')`. But it shows ὉA`. So what went wrong and what is the right way to print the green heart?

Comment: Python's Unicode escapes don't cover beyond the basic plane (which means 4 digit code points), and your font doesn't include the emoji symbols anyway.  You can print the heart as `'\u2665'` and maybe use ANSI escape codes to color it green.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'\u1F49'` is Greek Capital Letter Omicron with Dasia: `Ὁ`. `'\u1F49A'` is that same character plus an `A` literal. This is because `\u` expects a 16-bit hex value, or 4 hex characters. If you want to pass in a larger value you need to use capital `\U` and pass in the full 32-bit hex value:

```
print('\U0001F49A')
#
```

See the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type) for more info

Answer (score 1):

```
print("\u001b[32m\u2764")

print("\u001b[32m\U0001F49A")
```

Comment: That's not the same character. `❤` != `` even if you color it green.

Comment: change to this print("\u001b[32m\U0001F49A")

Comment: I suppose, but you really don't need the `\u001b[32m` part. It's already green — that's why it's called `'GREEN HEART'`. `\U0001F49A` is sufficient.